# IntegrityError Django ORM

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, unique

I am processing a file that contains consultation and medical data. I am also processing another file that contains only exam data.

As a good practice, I normalized the models leaving as follows:

```
class Medico(models.Model):
    codigo_medico = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Consulta(models.Model):
    numero_guia = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    data_consulta = models.DateField()
    valor_consulta = models.FloatField()
    codigo_medico = models.ForeignKey(Medico, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class META:
        ordering = ['data_consulta']


class Exame(models.Model):
    exame = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    valor_exame = models.FloatField()
    numero_guia_consulta = models.ForeignKey(Consulta, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class META:
        ordering = ['-valor_exame']
```

Note that the medical model has the ID field marked unique = true, because, regardless of the consultation, there can only be one doctor with a certain code.

I did the file processing and it worked perfectly. When trying to run the same file, knowing that the doctor's data is unique, I get IntegrationError (return Database.Cursor.execute (self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: relatorio_medico.codigo_medico)
This was expected. I did this processing precisely to get the repeated data. The question is, if a particular consultation file arrives, I will always have a doctor who is already registered at my base, so I need to deal with IntegratedError cases.

I tried to use try and except but to no avail.

How I did the implementation:

```
from relatorio.models import Exam, Consultation, Doctor
from django.db import IntegrityError as IE
from sqlite3 import IntegrityError


class CreateDataExams:
    """
    Cria os dados no banco de dados a partir de um lote de dados de exames.
    """
    def __init__(self, data_exams):
        self.data_exams = data_exams

    def create_exams(self):
        exams = []
        for item in self.data_exams[1:]:
            new_item = item.split(';')
            obj_exams = Exame(numero_guia_consulta=new_item[0], exame=new_item[1], valor_exame=new_item[2])
            exams.append(obj_exams)
        Exame.objects.bulk_create(exams)


class CreateDataAppointment:
    """
        Cria os dados no banco de dados a partir de um lote de dados de consulta.
    """
    def __init__(self, data_appointment):

        self.data_appointment = data_appointment
    def create_appointment(self):
        appointment = []
        medico = []
        del self.data_appointment[-1]
        for item in self.data_appointment[1:]:
            new_item = item.split(';')
            obj_medico = Medico(codigo_medico=new_item[1], nome=new_item[2])
            medico.append(obj_medico)

        Medico.objects.bulk_create(medico, batch_size=1000)

        for item in self.data_appointment[1:]:
            new_item = item.split(';')
            obj_appointment = Consulta(numero_guia=int(new_item[0]), data_consulta=new_item[3],
                                       valor_consulta=new_item[4],
                                   codigo_medico=Medico.objects.get(codigo_medico=int(new_item[1])))
        appointment.append(obj_appointment)
    Consulta.objects.bulk_create(appointment)
```

Below is a model of the data I am processing.
Exams:

[image]

Appointment:

[image]

Note that some doctor's code is repeated.

My question is: How to handle this case when saving doctor data, taking into account that I am processing by batch, due to the size of the files, which have more than 20k records?

I tried to use

```
from django.db import IntegrityError 

try:
    Medico.objects.bulk_create(medico, batch_size=1000)
except IntegrityError:
    Medico.objects.bulk_update(medico, ['nome'], batch_size=1000)
```

But without success. The same error happens.
The error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to create them one by one if they does not exist:

```
obj, created = Medico.objects.get_or_create(codigo_medico=new_item[1], nome=new_item[2])
```

Your object will be fetched from the database if already exists otherwise it will be inserted into the database.

You are also using another field which I assume is a name so looking for a row that has both the same id and the same string is slow since your `nome` field is not indexed other than it being an extra lookup anyway. So you can remove the name and just use the id which is pretty fast to look up.

```
exists = Medico.objects.filter(codigo_medico=new_item[1]).exists()
# only create a new object for bulk create if it doesn't exists
if not exists:
    obj_medico = Medico(codigo_medico=new_item[1], nome=new_item[2])
        medico.append(obj_medico)
```

To make it even more optimized, you can get all the ids and only create an object if the id isn't on that list:

```
doctor_ids = list(Medico.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True))

for item in self.data_appointment[1:]:
    new_item = item.split(';')
    if new_item[1] not in doctor_ids:
        obj_medico = Medico(codigo_medico=new_item[1], nome=new_item[2])
        medico.append(obj_medico)
```